# How can I remove the unnecessary characters after title and keyword list?

Tags: sectioning, errors, titles

I am getting unnecessary characters in my project. I have used a simple application but it is also generating those characters. I have tried to comment my previous changes but still I am getting those characters. I am also getting error with `\maketitle`.

My code is:

```
\documentclass[manuscript,screen]{acmart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\input{solidity-highlighting.tex}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{rotating} 


\usepackage{array, makecell}
\renewcommand\rotheadgape{}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{>{\bfseries\small}c|}{#2}}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
%\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

%\usepackage{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
%\title{TestingLatexCopy}
%\author{ }
%\date{August 2020}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}


\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2020}
\acmYear{2020}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}

\begin{document}
\title{A Testing}
%Survey on the Tools Support and Vulnerability Detection in Smart Contracts}


\author{A1author}
\authornote{A1Note}
\email{}
%\orcid{}
\author{A2author}
\authornotemark{A2Note}
\email{}
\affiliation{
  \institution{}
%  \streetaddress{P.O. Box 1212}
%  \city{Dublin}
%  \state{Ohio}
%  \postcode{43017-6221}
}
%\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{Trovato and Tobin, %et al.}
\begin{abstract}
  Testing abstract
\end{abstract}
\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
<concept>
<concept_id>10002978.10003022</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Security </concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
<concept>
<concept_id>10002944.10011122.10002945</concept_id>
<concept_desc>General overviews</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
</ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Security and privacy}
\ccsdesc[500]{General and reference}


%%
%% Keywords. The author(s) should pick words that accurately describe
%% the work being presented. Separate the keywords with commas.
\keywords{Testing1, Testing2, testing3}


\maketitle

\section{Introduction}



\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sourcefile-bib}


\end{document}
\endinput
```

My output image is:

[image: A3 Image_A2NOTE misplaced]

Link for files: i.e. Solidity-highlighting.tex, ACM_Reference Format file, acmart files, and .bib file kindly use the following link:
[Link for Project files](https://github.com/zak100/TemporaryFiles)

### After changes in my comment1, the image is:

[image: Still unnecessary characters]

Comment: The first "and" comes from having two empty author names. The marks probably come from the two \authornotemark. Put something (distinct) in all those empty arguments and you will sort it out.

Comment: Comment1:\author{A1}
\authornote{A1}
\email{}
%\orcid{}
\author{A1}
\authornotemark{A1},  Problem not solved, I have added the image above.

Comment: Edit your code so that we can see what you've done.  And put something *distinct* in the fields.  I would recommend putting the author name in `\author`.  If you're not needing `\authornote`, then comment it out.  The first "A1" is the author you've given, `A1*` is the first `\authornote`, and `A1+` is the second `\authornote`.

Comment: I have edited the code but I am still getting the same error. Why I am getting '1' and '234'. Please help me.

Comment: You are not showing us the code you have used to make that image.  Edit your post so that you have the actual code from your minimal working example, and the actual image that you get.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now I have uploded the new code after seeing phil's work. I am still gettig "A2Note" on top of title. Please guide me.

Comment: Note if author1 and author2 are same and I fill author note mark for author2 , I will get the same image as image2. i.e. author1=A1, author2=A1 and aothor2 note mark = A1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I change lines 35-44 to the following code, I get no errors in Overleaf:

```
\documentclass[manuscript,screen]{acmart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\input{solidity-highlighting.tex}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{rotating} 


\usepackage{array, makecell}
\renewcommand\rotheadgape{}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{>{\bfseries\small}c|}{#2}}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
%\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}


\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2020}
\acmYear{2020}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}

\begin{document}
\title{A Testing}
   
\author{A1}
% \authornote{}
% \email{}
%\orcid{}
\author{A2}
% \authornotemark{}
% \email{}
% \affiliation{
%   \institution{}
% }
\begin{abstract}
  Testing abstract
\end{abstract}
\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
<concept>
<concept_id>10002978.10003022</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Security </concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
<concept>
<concept_id>10002944.10011122.10002945</concept_id>
<concept_desc>General overviews</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
</ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Security and privacy}
\ccsdesc[500]{General and reference}


\keywords{Testing1, Testing2, testing3}


\maketitle

\section{Introduction}



\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sourcefile-bib}


\end{document}
\endinput
```

The only warning I get is: `` Package natbib Warning: Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 40. ``

[image]

Comment: Please write the whole code.

Comment: @user2994783, I've added the full code. You will need the files provided in the question to compile it.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the files on the GIT HUB folder. I have files already included in my project. I am still getting A2NOTE on top of title. You have not used the author note. I am afraid, should I add author note or not? Please guide me.

Comment: If I don't fill author note mark, I will get the same output as you are but does this mean that author note mark should not be used?

Comment: @user2994783, of course and by all means, do use it: `\author{A1}
\authornote{What could I put in here?}`. You will get † and * as footnotemarks so they are note confused with the regular footnotes. This is standard behavior and perfectly fine.